# Yahoo Answer it's really "Infinite Scroll" page? Python

Tags: html, selenium, web-crawler, infinite-scroll, yahoo

in this days i'm trying to scraping Yahoo Answer website in order to take questions in this [category](https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index/discover?sid=396545663).
I use Scrapy for the crawling but Selenium for the handle of the dynamic website.

After many try or methods i gain every time different result, in the first time i thought to scroll all the website use JS and when the label "Loading..." disappear stop the scroll-down.
But i realize that the loading stops in different moment.
Actually my code is this:

```
  time.sleep(5)
  wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        while True:
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(randint(4,6))
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -100000 );")
            time.sleep(randint(1,3))

            try:
                wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ya-infinite-scroll-message")))
           except TimeoutException:
                self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file("test_.jpg")
                break
```

And i can get many questions, but no all and the number of question scraped change every time.

Answer (score 2):

In fact this is a comment but for length is posted as answer!

I tried to test [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index/discover?sid=396545663) with selenium and javascript to see what happens. This is the same thing to my end. I tried javascript `scroll` function to scroll the view but getting  same result even from the different whitelisted ips too and different webdrivers. This is the code i tried so far.

```
import time,random,time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index/discover?sid=396545663")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul#ya-discover-tab")))

cntr = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class,'Bfc')]")
lst_scrlshgt = 0
lngth = 0
while True:
    global lngth
    topics = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='ya-discover-tile ya-discover-tile-qn Bfc P-14 Bdbx-1g Bgc-w']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", topics[-1])
    time.sleep(random.choice(range(4,7)))
    scrlshgt = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", cntr)
    if scrlshgt == lst_scrlshgt:
        break
    else:
        last_scrlshgt = scrlshgt
    lngth+=len(topics)
    print lngth





sample  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='Fz-14 Fw-b Clr-b Wow-bw title']")
for i in sample:
    print i.text.encode('utf-8') 

driver.quit()
```

I think [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) , [louis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906307/louis) or others can have a better answer.

Comment: I found 2093 at best?

Comment: i found about 1200-1400